# How to verify whether records exist for the last x days (calendar days) in SQL not using the between key word

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Want verify whether my table is having the records for the last 6 consecutive days in SQL

SNO    FLIGHT_DATE LANDINGS

45    9/1/2013  1

31  10/1/2013   1

32  11/1/2013   1

30  11/24/2013  1

27  11/25/2013  1

28  11/26/2013  1

29  11/26/2013  1

33  11/26/2013  1

26  11/30/2013  1

25  12/1/2013   1

34  12/1/2013   1

24  12/2/2013   1

35  12/3/2013   1

36  12/3/2013   1

44  12/4/2013   1

46  12/6/2013   1

47  12/6/2013   1

Comment: Please provide sample table structure and any queries you've tried thus far...

Comment: What's wrong with `BETWEEN`? Also, given that `BETWEEN` is pretty much just two relational operators fused together, `created_at > dateadd(day,-6,datediff(day,0,getdate())) AND created_at < GETDATE()` is a trivial, no `BETWEEN` solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT
      * 
FROM 
      Table1
WHERE
      FLIGHT_DATE  > dateadd(day,-6,datediff(day,0,getdate())) 
AND 
      FLIGHT_DATE < GETDATE();
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17383/5)

Comment: SELECT count (distinct(Flight_date)) FROM FLIGHT_TRACK_INFO 
WHERE 
Flight_date > ='11-30-2013' and Flight_date <='12-06-2013'   Iam using this code to get the count. Looking for any function that can verify records only by giving single paramenter in the above i am giving two parameters

Comment: even this query     SELECT
          * 
    FROM 
          Table1
    WHERE
          FLIGHT_DATE  > dateadd(day,-6,datediff(day,0,getdate())); will give you the same result as the above one, provided, you should not use hard codded values

Comment: 1 My table is having more than one entry for a day. 2.the query should provide the True of false based on last 6 consecutive days